# Expand time series with Pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm starting with the following DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {
    "Id": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "Value1": ["10", "20", "30"],
    "Period1": ["20:00", "20:30", "21:00"],
    "Value2": ["25", "40", "40"],
    "Period2": ["20:45", "00:00", "01:00"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

And given a custom time index:

```py
time_start = "2022-11-16 20:00:00.000000"
time_stop = "2022-11-17 09:00:00.000000"
time_index = pd.date_range(start=time_start, end=time_stop, freq="15Min")
```

I would like to obtain a dataframe for each Id in df where:

- the index is time_index
- the values are Value1 or Value2 depending on the time_index value of the row

For A, I should get:

```
                              Value
2022-11-16 20:00:00.000000    10
2022-11-16 20:15:00.000000    10
2022-11-16 20:30:00.000000    10
2022-11-16 20:45:00.000000    25
2022-11-16 21:00:00.000000    25
...                           ...
```

Comment: Have a look at `asfreq`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Setup
df["Period1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Period1"])
df["Period2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Period2"])
new_df = pd.DataFrame(time_index).rename(columns={0: "date"})
new_df["time"] = new_df["date"].dt.time

# Add values according to timestamps
for idx in df["Id"]:
    new_df.loc[
        new_df["time"] == df.loc[df["Id"] == idx, "Period1"].dt.time.values[0], idx
    ] = df.loc[df["Id"] == idx, "Value1"].values[0]
    new_df.loc[
        new_df["time"] == df.loc[df["Id"] == idx, "Period2"].dt.time.values[0], idx
    ] = df.loc[df["Id"] == idx, "Value2"].values[0]
    new_df = new_df.fillna(method="ffill")

# Cleanup
new_df = new_df.drop(columns="time").set_index("date").rename_axis(None, axis=0)
```

Then:

```py
print(pd.DataFrame(new_df.loc[:, "A"]).rename(columns={"A": "Value"}))

# Output
                    Value
2022-11-16 20:00:00    10
2022-11-16 20:15:00    10
2022-11-16 20:30:00    10
2022-11-16 20:45:00    25
2022-11-16 21:00:00    25
...                   ...
2022-11-17 08:00:00    25
2022-11-17 08:15:00    25
2022-11-17 08:30:00    25
2022-11-17 08:45:00    25
2022-11-17 09:00:00    25

[53 rows x 1 columns]
```

```py
print(pd.DataFrame(new_df.loc[:, "B"]).rename(columns={"B": "Value"}))

# Output
                    Value
2022-11-16 20:00:00   NaN
2022-11-16 20:15:00   NaN
2022-11-16 20:30:00    20
2022-11-16 20:45:00    20
2022-11-16 21:00:00    20
...                   ...
2022-11-17 08:00:00    40
2022-11-17 08:15:00    40
2022-11-17 08:30:00    40
2022-11-17 08:45:00    40
2022-11-17 09:00:00    40

[53 rows x 1 columns]
```

```py
print(pd.DataFrame(new_df.loc[:, "C"]).rename(columns={"C": "Value"}))

# Output
                    Value
2022-11-16 20:00:00   NaN
2022-11-16 20:15:00   NaN
2022-11-16 20:30:00   NaN
2022-11-16 20:45:00   NaN
2022-11-16 21:00:00    30
...                   ...
2022-11-17 08:00:00    40
2022-11-17 08:15:00    40
2022-11-17 08:30:00    40
2022-11-17 08:45:00    40
2022-11-17 09:00:00    40

[53 rows x 1 columns]
```